# Organize applications on a domain path rather than a subdomain for each?

Tags: force.com-sites

Is there a way to placesiteforce.com applications on a custom domain path, rather than having a subdomain for each ?

mydomain.com/app1 ->. app1 ...site.siteforce.com
mydomain.com/app2 ->. app2....site.siteforce.com

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can [Add a Custom URL](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.custom_url_add.htm&type=5). You'll find this option in Setup > User Interface > Sites and Domains > Custom URLs. This option is available in Professional, Enterprise, Performance, and Unlimited Editions.